# No reverse match during post

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

`reverse` in the views not returning to urls namespace

```
class UserCreateView(CreateView):
  model = User
  # form_class = UserCreationForm
  template_name = "users/create_user.html"
  success_url= "/users/create"

  def get_form_class(self):
      if self.request.user.user_level == 1 or self.request.user.user_level == 10:
         form_class = UserCreationForm
         return form_class

       elif self.request.user.user_level == 20:
          form_class = UserCreationFormCompanyManager
          return  form_class

      else:
          form_class = UserCreationFormHomeManager          
          return form_class

   def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
         form = self.get_form_class()
         user_level = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
         # form = UserCreationFormHomeManager(request.POST)
      if request.method=='POST':
         form = UserCreationFormCompanyManager(request.POST)
         if user_level == 20:
             if form.is_valid():
                obj = form.save(commit=False)
                obj.company = self.request.user.company
                obj.password = make_password(form.cleaned_data['password'])
                obj.save()
                return obj

      elif user_level == 30:
         if request.method=='POST':
            form = UserCreationFormHomeManager(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                obj = form.save(commit=False)
                obj.company = self.request.user.company
                obj.home = self.request.user.home
                obj.password = make_password(form.cleaned_data['password'])
                obj.save()  
                return obj
      else:
         if request.method=='POST':
            form = UserCreationFormHomeManager(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                obj.password = make_password(form.cleaned_data['password'])
                obj = form.save()
                return obj

       return  reverse('create-user')`

user_create_view = UserCreateView.as_view()
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from sharefile.users.views import (
    user_list_view,
    user_redirect_view,
    user_update_view,
    user_detail_view,
    user_create_view,
    home_create_view,
    company_create_view,
)

app_name = "users"
urlpatterns = [
    path("", view=user_list_view, name="list"),
    path("~redirect/", view=user_redirect_view, name="redirect"),
    path("~update/", view=user_update_view, name="update"),
    path("user/<str:username>/", view=user_detail_view, name="detail"),
    path("create/", view=user_create_view, name="create-user"),
    path("create-home/", view=home_create_view, name="create-home"),
    path("create-company/", view=company_create_view, name="create-company"),
    # path("create-group/", view=group_create_view, name="create-group"),
    # path("create-permission/", view=permission_create_view, name="create-permission"),

]
```

Trace back :

```
traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/bishwa/PycharmProjects/sharefile/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "/home/bishwa/PycharmProjects/sharefile/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 128, in _get_response
response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
File "/home/bishwa/PycharmProjects/sharefile/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 52, in inner
return func(*args, **kwds)
File "/home/bishwa/PycharmProjects/sharefile/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 69, in view
return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/bishwa/PycharmProjects/sharefile/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 89, in dispatch
return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/bishwa/PycharmProjects/sharefile/sharefile/users/views.py", line 67, in post
return  reverse('create-user')
File "/home/bishwa/PycharmProjects/sharefile/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/base.py", line 90, in reverse
return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
File "/home/bishwa/PycharmProjects/sharefile/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 634, in _reverse_with_prefix
raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'create-user' not found. 'create-user' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
 [11/Jan/2019 15:52:19] "POST /users/create/ HTTP/1.1" 500 117938
```

Comment: add your full urls.py

Comment: @ShafikurRahman I have added urls.py

Comment: You may try my answer. Import UserCreateView in urls.py

Comment: I tried by importing as you said and the error is `Reverse for 'create-user' not found. 'create-user' is not a valid view function or pattern name.`

Comment: It may be for your url not have a valid view function

Comment: It is the same view above that I am redirecting  after success

Comment: You have `app_name = "users"`, therefore you should use `reverse('users:create-user')`.